# jquery continuous horizontal scroll not working

Tags: jquery, horizontal-scrolling

I want the contents inside my div to be continuously scrolled horizontally and it is not working. any help will be appreciated

```
<div id="mydivid">This text needs to be scrolled horizontally continuously</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
         jQuery("#mydivid")
             .stop()
             .animate({ left: "-=100px" }, 2000 );
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this [Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4b8ry47h/)

you can simply use `marquee`

```
<div id="mydivid"><marquee>This text needs to be scrolled horizontally continuously</marquee></div>
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element : "*The marquee tag is a non-standard HTML element [...] The W3C advises against its use in HTML documents.*"

Comment: @coding-cracker Is it possible to let me know the error in my above jquery code ? Thanks